# Surface integrals help (parametrise and solve box w/ force)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

I have this question which states

> Let S be the surface of the box bounded by the six planes $$x=0,x=2,y=0,y=4,z=0,z=1$$
> $\vec{n}$ is the outward normal and
> $$\vec{F}(x,y,z) = (y^2-\sin(yz))\vec{i} + (y-z) \vec{j} + (x^2y\sin(x) + x^2 + y^2)\vec{k}$$
> Pick $S_{1}$ to be one of the six faces of S. Parametrise $S_{1}$ and express
> $$\int\int_{S_{1}} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}dS$$ as a double integral.

> Evaluate $$\int\int_{S}\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}dS$$
> where S and $\vec{F}$ are defined as above

So my initial thoughts let us take the top of the box and just parametrise is with (0,0,k) being the normal vector [for $S_{1}$] and then once we express it as a double integral we move to the second part where my question lies.

If we do the same process of using the normal which points outwards and do them in pairs we have a "pair" which adds to $0$ i.e.

$$\int\int_{S_{1}} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}dS + \int\int_{S_{1}}\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}dS$$

and if we repeat this process for each face with each pair we obtain

$$\int\int_{S}\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}dS = 0$$

> I was hoping someone could either correct me or advise me how to continue with this problem.

Thank you

Comment: No you cannot assume they will all cancel out. For example, when you are finding for plane $y = 0$, you will put value of $y = 0$ whereas for plane $y = 4$, you will put value of $y = 4$ so while the normal vectors are in opposite directions, you have different values of $y$ so they may not necessarily cancel out.

Comment: But when you are doing for the entire surface, you can apply divergence theorem. That would simplify it.

Comment: @MathLover That was my second thought to use the divergence theorem, thank you

Comment: You are welcome. If you get stuck, edit your question with the progress you make and we can help.

Comment: Formatting tip.  If you use `\sin`, `\log` and so on, your posts will be easier to read.

Comment: @saulspatz Will take into account, thanks for the help guys (/girls)